# Open built-in window by a command

Tags: windows-10, command-line

I always use `Win+R` then input a `sysdm.cpl` to open a window to set the *PATH* in my *Windows 10*, but I don't know why this command will work. Can anyone can give me a explanation for it? And now, if I right-click the *ThisPC*, then I click the *Properties* I can open a *properties window*. Can I open this window by another command in `Win+R`?

Furthermore, how to know which window can be open by those command in *Windows 10*?

---

As the answer of [techturtle](https://superuser.com/users/118184/techturtle) says:

> You can access just about any Control Panel item if you know the name
>   of its actual command

But actually my question is how to find those commands about any windows?

Comment: The command works because you are directly accessing a [Windows control panel applet](https://support.microsoft.com/en-ph/help/192806/how-to-run-control-panel-tools-by-typing-a-command) by name via the Run command (Win + R). Not sure what the second half of your question means but if I am guessing correctly, you can use Win + R and "control system" to get the same Window as "ThisPC -> Properties". Per @techturtle's answer, there are quite a few resources to for these kinds of commands.

Comment: @Anaksunaman Crazy comment,I think it desever a answer. Actually I have read that answer but I don't know you how to find the command of  `control system`.Could you give some explaination for it?

Comment: I have posted a more complete answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Adding a real answer to your question** because existing answers do not address this.

> But actually my question is how to find those command about any windows?

▶ All control panel applets are registered in Registry database under `HKCR\CLSID`. This is described in MSDN article [How to Register Executable Control Panel Items](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh127450(v=vs.85).aspx).

**Example:** You can find there for example this registry key and its data:

```
{A8A91A66-3A7D-4424-8D24-04E180695C7A}
```

`System.ApplicationName`: **`Microsoft.DevicesAndPrinters`**    (← this is value you can refer to)
`System.ControlPanel.Category`: **`2`**

So the Windows creates list of all such keys (Registry "folders") which qualify and creates Control Panel items from them.

**Summary:** You can learn all commands available in *your* Windows from Registry. Use [Nirsoft RegScanner](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/regscanner.html) to list all registered items at once (or their related commands etc.) by searching for specific registry value, for example `System.ApplicationName`.

Further reading (main topic): [Implementing Control Panel Items](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144185(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Amazing........

Answer (score 3):

`.cpl` files are usually Control Panel widgets.  Typing `sysdm.cpl` in the Run box is the same as if you went to the Control Panel, clicked on System, then clicked on Advanced System Settings.  You can access just about any Control Panel item if you know the name of its actual command.  The My Computer properties window you mentioned can be accessed by a keyboard shortcut of <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Pause/Break</kbd>.

https://www.groovypost.com/howto/windows-10-keyboard-shortcuts/ has a very comprehensive list of shortcut keys you can use and items you can type into the Run box to go directly to a variety of Windows settings and options.

Comment: But how to know the name of any Control Panel item?Is there any method?You link just give a several command..

Comment: I don't know how to directly discover the name of a specific command.  Some can be found using Task Manager or [Process Explorer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer).  In the list I linked, you can do a search for the title or description of the feature you want and it's likely to find it.

Answer (score 1):

Per this [Microsoft article](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/executing-control-panel-items) —

> The user or an application can start a Control Panel item by executing it directly from the command line prompt.

The command works because you are directly accessing a Windows [control panel applet](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/how-to-run-control-panel-tools-by-typing-a-command-bce95b4d-e8c2-1cd0-ee0d-027679d520a6) (the *.cpl* extension) by name via the Run command (<kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>).

[image: sysdm]

This same file is linked to certain selections in *Control Panel\System and Security\System* as well, such as *Advanced system settings* or changing your computer's name.

> If I right-click *ThisPC* and then I click *Properties*, I can open a properties window. Can I open this window with another command in Win+R?

To access *Control Panel\System and Security\System* (which is the same as right-clicking *ThisPC* → *Properties*) there is a different method — <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> then type *"control system"*.

[image: control panel]

[image: control panel 32]

As you can see, *"system"* acts as a parameter to *control.exe* (indicating which panel to show).

> How can I find these commands to Run any given window?

Please forgive me if I misunderstand anything or go over anything you already know. =)

Unfortunately, similar to @techturtle, I am not aware of any command to list just the possible Control Panel options directly.

*Update: As @miroxlav's answer suggests, you can use utilities to go through the registry. This could have the added benefit of identifying custom, non-standard Control Panel items (such as those installed by certain software or by a computer manufacturer).*

Specifically for the Control Panel, there is also sometimes overlap between commands. For instance, *"control date/time*", *"control /name Microsoft.DateAndTime"*, *"control timedate.cpl"* and *"timedate.cpl*" all bring up the *Date/Time* settings panel on Windows 7/8/10.

**Control Panel Item Lists**

However, there are some helpful lists produced by Microsoft. In addition to the [official list of default Control Panel applets/commands](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/how-to-run-control-panel-tools-by-typing-a-command-bce95b4d-e8c2-1cd0-ee0d-027679d520a6) linked earlier, [Microsoft also has a listing of all the canonical (official) names for every default Control Panel item](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/controlpanel-canonical-names).

This second set of items can generally be opened with <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> and then by entering *"control /name"* along with the proper name listed e.g *"Microsoft.Troubleshooting"*.

[image: Troubleshooting Example]

**Notes**

- For clarity, some of these commands may not work with *Start → Search* (e.g. *"sysdm.cpl"* will but *"control access.cpl"* will not). All commands should be run with <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> (as you have).
- [This blog entry seems to have a good list of duplicate Control Panel commands](https://web.archive.org/web/20180326110932/http://blog.anakage.co.in/commands-to-start-control-panel-items-in-windows-from-command-prompt/).
- In case you remember what a panel looks like but can't recall its name, [this link seems to have a pretty complete list of all the possible control panel items with screenshots](https://www.lifewire.com/list-of-control-panel-applets-in-windows-2626120). Currently you have to click on "Show Full Article" to see all the entries.
- @techturtle's Groovypost link is interesting because it has command-line/Run details for non-Control Panel items as well, such as [Microsoft Management Console Snap-Ins](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/technet-magazine/hh505659(v=msdn.10)) (ending with *.msc*). These could be useful since e.g. something like the *Services* panel is not part of the Control Panel but it can be started with *"services.msc"*.

Comment: Thanks very much..your answer packed a lot information..:)

Comment: Your welcome... glad to help. =)